# Query document with the max sub field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

Suppose we have some documents as following:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "title": "ABC",
    "version": 1
   },
  "status": "Submitted",
  ....
}

{
  "_id": {
    "title": "ABC",
    "version": 2
   },
  "status": "Submitted",
  ....
}

{
  "_id": {
    "title": "XYZ",
    "version": 1
   },
  "status": "Submitted",
  ....
}
```

How can I get the documents with the max `version` for every different `title`?

For the dataset above, the result should be:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "title": "ABC",
    "version": 2
   },
  "status": "Submitted",
  ....
}

{
  "_id": {
    "title": "XYZ",
    "version": 1
   },
  "status": "Submitted",
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea here is to order the documents by the `version` key first, group the documents by the `title` key and return the first document in the group when ordered. So, the operators invited to the aggregation pipeline show here will be the the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)**, **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** and **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** (which reshapes the aggregated documents to be in the desired result schema).

Now within the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline you'd need the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** operator (or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** depending on the direction which you ordered the documents in the previous **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline) to map the top document's field when ordered.

Consider the following play in mongo shell:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "_id.version": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.title",
            "id": { "$first": "$_id" },
            "status": { "$first": "$status" }
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$id",
            "status": 1,
            ...
        } 
    }
])
```

---

For the mongoTemplate equivalent:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    sort(DESC, "_id.version"),
    group("_id.title"), 
        .first("status").as("status")
        ...
    project("id").previousOperation().and("status").and(...)
);
```

---

You've got another alternative of inviting the **[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT)** system variable to your **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline as means to return the full document. Consider the following approach:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "_id.version": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.title",            
            "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$doc._id",
            "status": "$doc.status",
            ...
        } 
    }
])
```

which would translate to

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    sort(DESC, "_id.version"),
    group("_id.title"), 
        .first(ROOT).as("doc")
    project("doc.status").as("status")...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/).

> Returns the maximum value. $max compares both value and type, using the specified BSON comparison order for values of different types.

You can use following query:-

```
aggregate(
[
 {
   $project:
     {
       _id: "$_id.title",
       version: { $max: "$_id.version" },
       status : "$status"
     }
 }
])
```

I did not try the query. Let me know if any error you are getting.

Hope this will help.